# Adjective describing an airplane that's in the boarding process?

Tags: word-request

An [adjective] airplane.

> Definition: In the process of having passengers go on board; being boarded by passengers.

Does '**boarding**' fit?

Comment: I'm not really sure we can give you an adjective that will fit your exact example... "An airplane in the boarding process" would be fine but the airplane isn't doing anything... it's **being** boarded. It's currently "gated" (sitting at the gate) but that doesn't imply that it's being deboarded or boarded or cleaned.

Comment: Hi William, welcome to ELL. Please use the **edit** button to provide a bit more information about what you want to know.

Comment: Is there a word you have in mind, like in a different language?

Comment: You do sometimes hear things like "Flight 317 is boarding now."  But you don't hear that the airplane itself is boarding, because boarding is what the people getting on the plane are doing.   "being boarded" is probably the best answer.

Comment: Maybe *enplaning airplane*. The only [link](https://www.google.com/search?biw=911&bih=445&tbm=bks&q=%22enplaning+airplane%22&oq=%22enplaning+airplane%22&gs_l=serp.3..33i160k1.4741.7841.0.8106.2.2.0.0.0.0.238.454.2-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.237.dd8KYKh6zOg) I found on Google refers to the passengers getting on a plane. But it seems to me one could apply it to the plane itelf.

Answer (score 5):

People use *a boarding (air)plane* to describe an airplane that is in the process of boarding.

In context, its use appears quite natural.

> Have you ever tried to move against the flow on a boarding plane?

http://www.angelfire.com/weird/junkyard/doubles.html

> According to Genevieve, the anxiety of an empty middle seat on a boarding plane is a feeling they know well.

http://www.thereporteronline.com/general-news/20150123/finalist-in-super-bowl-ad-competition-from-lansdale

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

> An enplaning airplane

Most people might not be familiar with the word *[enplaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enplaning)*. It is the opposite of *deplaning*. See the included link to 'enplane' at the free dictionary dot com.

The only example I could find on Google:

*United States Aviation Reports - Volume 4 - Page 2936*:

> U. S., 1975 USAvR 31 A valid pre-flight airport security check of enplaning airplane passengers for bombs and weapons does not become illegal because of the unexpected discovery of cocaine as an incident of the bomb and weapons ...

([link](https://www.google.com/search?biw=911&bih=445&tbm=bks&q=%22enplaning+airplane%22&oq=%22enplaning+airplane%22&gs_l=serp.3..33i160k1.4741.7841.0.8106.2.2.0.0.0.0.238.454.2-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.237.dd8KYKh6zOg))

Actually this refers to the *airplane passengers*. But it seems to me *deplane* and *enplane* can be used of airplanes themselves.

I know *Wait until the airplane deplanes* is possible, because I heard a flight attendant say it over the public address system. So I don't think it's a stretch to say *an enplaning airplane*, although *a boarding airplane*, as Jim, suggests, would use a word that is more common.

Comment: I agree that *an enplaning plane* makes sense